ADF How to retrieve the SOQL Query statements sent during an Upsert in a Copy Activity Salesforce API 2.0
I'm working on ADF in a copy activity, sending thousands of records to Salesforce Sandbox. I'm encountering errors and need to retrieve the SOQL Query statements sent during an Upsert. Is there any way to retrieve them?
I've tried using the log of the copy activity, but it doesn't record the SOQL Query scripts. I also checked the monitor, but I only see various statistics, not the sent scripts.
This is the source code in copy activity:
{
"name": "DEV_CO_ContactToSalesforce",
"type": "Copy",
"dependsOn": [
    {
        "activity": "DEV_FOR_ GoOverListObjectsDownload",
        "dependencyConditions": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    }
],
"policy": {
    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
    "retry": 0,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    "secureOutput": false,
    "secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
    "source": {
        "type": "ParquetSource",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
            "recursive": true,
            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "ParquetReadSettings"
        }
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "SalesforceSink",
        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
        "writeBehavior": "upsert",
        "externalIdFieldName": "Id",
        "ignoreNullValues": false
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "parallelCopies": 2,
    "logSettings": {
        "enableCopyActivityLog": true,
        "copyActivityLogSettings": {
            "logLevel": "Info",
            "enableReliableLogging": false
        },
        "logLocationSettings": {
            "linkedServiceName": {
                "referenceName": "link_svc_ccvadfdevstorage_blob",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "path": "dev-crm/RAW/ADFLogging"
        }
    },
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
},
"inputs": [
    {
        "referenceName": "DEV_DS_CCV_Parquet_w_param",
        "type": "DatasetReference",
        "parameters": {
            "ds_file_name": {
                "value": "@concat('PROCESSED/', pipeline().globalParameters.DEV_ContactParquetFileNameProc)",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "ds_obj_name": "Contact"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": [
    {
        "referenceName": "DEV_DS_SandoxDca1",
        "type": "DatasetReference",
        "parameters": {
            "objectName": "Contact"
        }
    }
]

}

Are you using any queries in the copy activity to do the upsert? Can you provide your copy activity source and sink configurations?

Hi Rakesh, I'm not using any queries, I'm puting the code source in the question now.

Why will it record the SOQL query script, when no query script is used.? For better understanding, share the error message you get.

There's no "query done during upsert". Salesforce figures out whether to perform insert or update internally. And if you go deep under the API layer I don't think there would be a query, you'd probably see something like Oracle MERGE. And what good would it do to you, why do you need it?
If you're having errors thrown from customisations (triggers, flows etc) best would be to enable Setup -> Debug Logs for the user performing the load.
